# CSS Hover doesn't accept class name

Tags: css, class, hover, html-lists

I'm trying to make an accordian like menu to work.
I've found a nice one here https://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-onclick-vertical-metal-menu, and now I'm trying to make adjustments.
The ideia is to change the color of sub menu options, with **CSS hover**.
But the problem is: I can't find a way to make different colors to work with hover, inside sub menus...
Take a look at these css lines:

```
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_1            {background:red         url("Down_Arrow.png") no-repeat;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_2            {background:lime        url("Down_Arrow.png") no-repeat;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_3            {background:yellow      url("Down_Arrow.png") no-repeat;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_4            {background:lightgray   url("Down_Arrow.png") no-repeat;}

#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_1:focus         {background:mediumvioletred;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_2:focus         {background:limegreen;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_3:focus         {background:orange;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_4:focus         {background:gray;}

#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_1:active        {background:mediumvioletred;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_2:active        {background:limegreen;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_3:active        {background:orange;}
#Top_Menu a.SubMenu_4:active        {background:gray;}

#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_1:hover      {background-color:mediumvioletred;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_2:hover      {background-color:limegreen;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_3:hover      {background-color:orange;}
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_4:hover      {background-color:gray;}

#Top_Menu ul li a.SubMenu_1:hover   {background-color:red;     color:black;}
#Top_Menu ul li a.SubMenu_2:hover   {background-color:lime;    color:black;}
#Top_Menu ul li a.SubMenu_3:hover   {background-color:yellow;  color:black;}
#Top_Menu ul li a:hover             {background-color:magenta; color:black;}
```

All code: https://jsfiddle.net/rbon/t3nefas3/1/

Sub menus are colored red, lime, yellow and lightgray.
Upon user action (click or hover), they become mediumvioletred, limegreen, orange and gray.
Everything seems to be alright... BUT the last 4 lines doesn't do the job as expected (well, the way I imagine it should).
I wished sub menus options would turn to original sub menu colors (red, lime, yellow, lightgray), but they ALL become magenta (I used magenta just to make it clearer).
What's the secret behind the last line???

```
#Top_Menu ul li a:hover             {background-color:magenta; color:black;}
```

I wished something like this could work instead:

```
#Top_Menu ul li a.SubMenu_4:hover   {background-color:lightgray;` color:black;}
```

What's going on???
The first 3 sub menus have classes SubMenu_1 to 3, and they work except for the last sequence of instructions **(when it comes to '#Top_Menu ul li a.CLASS_NAME:hover')**.
And that very last one... I can't use the SubMenu_4 class name, cause it simply makes NO color to be shown...

A minor issue: the outer div (class Menu) isn't aligning to its mandatory cordinates **(top=0px)**. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not right; you are selecting a link with a class that does not exist.

Try:

```
#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_1 ~ ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_2 ~ ul li a:hover {
  background-color: lime;
  color: black;
}

#Top_Menu li a.SubMenu_3 ~ ul li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#Top_Menu li a ~ ul li a:hover {
  background-color: magenta;
  color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3nefas3/2/

Or add the class missing to each of the sub-level links.

Comment: Wow !!! Perfect!!! Thank you very much! BUT... "...a class that do not exist"... the original code was working with that magenta color... how come if the class doesn't exist? I imagined it wasn't taking any class as argument, and was working for everything. Because the jsfiddle I mentioned shows that...